# WGS84 Lon/Lat to UTM in R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, utm

I know this question was asked several times and I searched plenty of past answers and tried plenty of variations but I couldn't transform my coordinates correctly.

My coordinates (stored in a .csv) are given in WGS84 Lon/Lat decimal degree format.
For example I have the coordinate Lat: 38.906 Lon: -120.71
This should output the UTM coordinates: 698568.503, 4308838.330
But if I do (following [this](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/19879_7e13ab80d5ed416c8e235bd6bb93cf3e.html) instructions):

```
cord.dec = SpatialPoints(cbind(mycsv$Longitude, 
                               - mycsv$Latitude), 
                         proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat"))
cord.UTM <- spTransform(cord.dec, CRS("+init=epsg:32610"))

# add coordinates to UTM list
utm$X=cord.UTM@coords[,1]
utm$Y=cord.UTM@coords[,2]
```

I get: 698714, -4308793 which is obviously not correct.

I tried [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18641016/7435045) instruction on this topic. But if I do:

```
lonlat.coordinates <- data.frame(ID = 1:length(mycsv$Latitude), 
                      Y_LAT = mycsv$Latitude,
                      X_LON = mycsv$Longitude)

coordinates(lonlat.coo) <- c('X_LON', 'Y_LAT')
```

I get:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(object, , value) : undefined columns selected

Can anyone please help me?

Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You've got a minus sign before the Latitude:**

```
cord.dec = SpatialPoints(cbind(mycsv$Longitude, 
                               - mycsv$Latitude),
```

Which is giving you a negative Y coordinate:

"I get: 698714, -4308793 which is obviously not correct."

Fix that and you get:

```
> cord.dec = SpatialPoints(cbind(mycsv$Longitude,mycsv$Latitude),proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat"))
> spTransform(cord.dec, CRS("+init=epsg:32610"))
SpatialPoints:
     coords.x1 coords.x2
[1,]  698568.5   4308838
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +init=epsg:32610 +proj=utm
+zone=10 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

which is "This should output the UTM coordinates: 698568.503, 4308838.330 " to about 1m.

Answer (score 0):

I get

```r
x <- cbind(-120.71, 38.906) 
library(sp)
cord.dec = SpatialPoints(x, proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat"))
coordinates(spTransform(cord.dec, CRS("+init=epsg:32610")))
#>      coords.x1 coords.x2
#> [1,]  698568.5   4308838

## sf is the new and entirely different 'sp' plus life raft
sf::sf_project(from = "EPSG:4326", to = "EPSG:32610", x)
#>          [,1]    [,2]
#> [1,] 698568.5 4308838
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

which looks like what you said you expect. Please share your `sessionInfo()` and a reproducible example 'reprex' so we can dig in.

Comment: I can't activate the 'sf' library with library('sf'). I did install it with install.packages('sf') but I got some errors like: "ERROR: dependency ‘units’ is not available for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/home/MYUSER/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/sf’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status". Else, what are you looking for in sessionInfo() (Output is too long to be in sackexchanges comments)?

Comment: you don't really need sf, that's just an alt pathway in my reprex - I mean for the code you run above, where you get the wrong answer - either you are mistaken in your report, or there's some real problem. If you run `sessionInfo()` you get a printed summary of your R session, it's helpful to record what your set up is (i.e. maybe it's an out of date buggy R version or something).

Comment: I would note that the new roll out of sf with the PROJ WKT format is no longer going to support EPSG.

Comment: that's not true, lots of different inputs are supported as are new forms of 'AUTH:code' - sf does have its own rules on top of the PROJ/GDAL stuff, but that's not one of them (you can't have a valid sfc with `$input = epsg` and `$wkt = NULL` but that's very much an sf quirk )

Comment: So I tried now: `coord <- cbind(mycsv$Longitude, mycsv$Latitude)
cord.dec = SpatialPoints(coord, proj4string=CRS('+proj=longlat'))
cord.UTM <- coordinates(spTransform(cord.dec, CRS('+init=epsg:32610')))` and I'm getting 698714.3/4308793 which is better but still way off.  sessionInfo(): attached base packages: stats, graphics, grDevices utils, datasets, methods, base  other attached packages: stringr_1.4.0, raster_3.1-5, lubridate_1.7.8 rgdal_1.5-8  R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: and loaded via a namespace (and not attached): compiler_4.0.2, magrittr_1.5, generics_0.0.2, tools_4.0.2, Rcpp_1.0.4.6, stringi_1.4.6, codetools_0.2-16 grid_4.0.2, lattice_0.20-41